# Embedded collectionView inside collectionViewCell not pinning to safe area layout

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to recreate instagrams profile screens, but I have run into an issue where I cannot pin an embedded collectionView to the safe area layout.

Here is a video of what the issues is:

https://streamable.com/gitpo0

There are 32 cells inside the embedded collectionView and when scrolling, to the bottom, you cannot see the last 5 (unless forcing the scroll upwards, as per the video).

And here is an example project:

https://github.com/mickey1980/TestProject

I thought it should be a case of pinning the embedded collectionView to the super.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, but that doesn't seem to work.

What I did notice when running debugging the app in the simulator, is that there are extra contraints being added to the collectoinView:

[image]

[image]

which is larger than the screen.

If I add a constant height to the collectionView inside the cell, it works as expected, but that isn't quite what I want.

I appreciate there is a gap in my knowledge, hopefully someone could point me in the right direction.

I have tried to follow Apples, Modern Collection view design, so this is built with diffable data sources and composition layouts, which is very new to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Having thought about this, I think that the embedded collectionView isn't taking into consideration the header of the outer collectionView.  So the height is calculated correctly albeit going off the screen due to the supplementaryHeader, which the embedded collectionView isn't aware of.  I'm still a little unsure how to solve this however?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly changing this line from your repo in DemoViewController:

```
self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

to

```
self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This should do the trick - You're pinning to the safe area rather than just to the views bottom anchor which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying, did you test this? Is the scrolling in the embedded collection view now working correctly? It isn't for me.

Comment: Along with the change above it looks like you'll need to disable scrolling in `PostScreenCell` too. I'm unsure of the exact scroll behaviour you're after but this will fix the bottom spacing.

Comment: Thanks, when you scroll do you see all the cells? There are 32 cells, and at the moment 5 of those are getting cut off.

Comment: Let's take it to a room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240491/swiftuicompositionallayout